# Sequelize HasMany not working

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, sequelize.js

I am using [sails-hook-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-sequelize) and [sails-hook-sequelize-blueprints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-sequelize-blueprints) in my [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) app.

I have a model called `Site`.

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        }
    },
    associations: function() {
        Site.hasMany(Templates, {
            as: 'templates'
        });
    }
};
```

Each site has more than one `Templates` associated to it.

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

I get an error saying

```
/user/myproject/node_modules/sails-hook-sequelize-blueprints/index.js:362
              var alias = foreign.as || foreign.name || foreign;
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'as' of undefined
```

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a `foreignKey` to the `hasMany` definition:

```
    Site.hasMany(Templates, {
        as: 'templates',
        foreignKey: 'SiteId'
    });
```

and add the `belongsTo` association to the `Templates` model definition:

```
    Templates.belongsTo(Site) // this will add SiteId to the Templates table
```

It's good practice to be consistent with your naming too - model names should be singular (`Template` rather than `Templates`) and these relationships and their following methods will be more self explanatory.  Sequelize will pluralise where it makes sense (i.e. you're dealing with many instances).

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, it's because your variable 'foreign' is undefined and you try to read a property of undefined.